# How to connect to a NAS share using a different user name?

Tags: snow-leopard, nas

I have an iMac running OSX 10.6.8 that automounts a NAS share from a D-Link DNS-320 2-bay Network Attached Storage. On the NAS, both users "user1" and "user2" are members of group "group1".

My user logs in as "user1", but the iMac connects/authenticates to the NAS as "user2".  I am able to disconnect user2 then manually "Connect As..." user1, but even after doing so, the share sometimes shows "Connected as user2". I just want to connect as user1.

How do I get OSX to forget about user2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to remove the stored value in KeyChain (there were multiple for the user; had to find the one specific to the IP of my NAS).